Application of Crank-Nicholson for PDE with constant term
I have the differential equation
$$
\lambda^2 \frac{\partial^2 V(x,t)}{\partial x^2}-\tau \frac{\partial V(x,t)}{\partial t}=CV(x,t)+D
$$
which I want to solve using the Crank-Nicholson method, applying the finite difference method I get
$$
\lambda^2\left[\frac{(V^{n+1}\_{i+1}-2V^{n+1}\_{i}+V^{n+1}\_{i-1})+(V^{n}\_{i+1}-2V^{n}\_{i}+V^{n}\_{i-1})}{2\Delta x^2}\right]-\tau \left[\frac{V^{n+1}\_{i}-V_i^n}{\Delta t}\right]=C\left[\frac{V_i^n+V^{n+1}\_{i}}{2}\right]+D
$$
some rewriting will lead to the matrix equation
$$
A\mathbf{V}^{n+1}=B\mathbf{V}^{n}+\mathbf{D}
$$
where $\mathbf{V}^n=(V^n_0,V^n_1,\dots,V^n_{N+1})^T$. The matrices A and B have elements on their diagonal and two off diagonals. The diagonal of $A$ is $\alpha+\beta+C/2$ and its off diagonals are $-\alpha/2$. The diagonal of $B$ is $-\alpha+\beta-C/2$ and its off diagonals are $\alpha/2$, where $\alpha =\lambda^2/\Delta x^2$ and $\beta=\tau/\Delta t$. The constant vector $\mathbf{D}$ is a vector with all elements being equal to $D$. I have solved this numerically with $D=0$ and get sensible results however with $D\neq 0$ I don't get sensible results, is there any considerations I need to make with this new term? Numerically what I am doing is using np.linalg.solve(A, C) where $C=B\mathbf{V}^{n}+\mathbf{D}$.
